# How to achieve 3d touch (peek and pop) in react native

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation, peek-pop

how can I implement this functionality in my react-native app?

[image]

Is react-navigation provide this by default?

here are some related links:

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/3301

https://github.com/osdnk/peek-and-pop [404 in npm]

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3113

https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/pull/2186

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ContextMenu , `UIContextMenuInteraction` in iOS 13.

Please check below lib.

https://github.com/mpiannucci/react-native-context-menu-view

https://www.google.com/search?q=UIContextMenuInteraction

Comment: can I load the screen into it? like i would pass my route name and props and it will show that route screen in ContextMenu

Comment: yes, check examples https://github.com/mpiannucci/react-native-context-menu-view/tree/main/example

Comment: ok, let me check and let you know

Comment: Hey Toseef, what is the event for the main ContextMenu click? onPress only fires for actions click.